# Django: Inherit Permissions from abstract models?

Tags: django, django-models, abstract, django-permissions

Is it possible to inherit permissions from an abstract model in Django?
I can not really find anything about that. For me this doesn't work!

```
class PublishBase(models.Model): 
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        get_latest_by = 'created'
        permissions = (('change_foreign_items',
                        "Can change other user's items"),)
```

**EDIT:** Not working means it fails silently. Permission is not created, as it wouldn't exist on the models inheriting from this class.

Comment: "does not work" means exactly what? can you elaborate?

Comment: See edit. and i can't find any documentation, if that is supposed to work or not...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is link for resolve you issue: http://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/10686
Need to apply patch... But it realy works.

Comment: As I get it permissions should also be inherited without this patch?(if no explicit permissions defined in children, and the %(class)s problem)

Answer (score 11):

The permissions are not inherited, if the child class also defines its own `class Meta`.
I found the following work-around, which saves from having to define the permissions again on every child model:

```
class AbstractBaseModel(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        permissions = (("test_permission","test permission"),)


class SomeClass(AbstractBaseModel):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name="Name")

    class Meta(AbstractBaseModel.Meta):
        verbose_name = ....
```

No need to set abstract to false in the child Meta class, since Django sets it in the parent to False when processing it! http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/models/#meta-inheritance

Comment: This is still the case in Django 1.10.5. Have applied this same workaround to get abstract permissions added to inherited models, otherwise makemigrations doesn't find the permissions.

Comment: I want to add some new permissions in inherited class. What will be correct way to go about it?

Answer (score 2):

My work-around:

```
class AbstractModelBase(models.base.ModelBase):

    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):
        new = super(AbstractModelBase, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
        new._meta.permissions += (("abstract_permission", "Abstract permission"),)
        return new


class AbstractModel(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = AbstractModelBase

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at the following meta implementation,
it adds read permissions to all django models that set MyModelMeta Class to be thier **metaclass**:

```
class MyModelMeta(ModelBase):
    # add a read permission to each MyModelMeta model
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, attrs):

        Meta = None

        if "Meta" in attrs:
            Meta = attrs.get("Meta")
            if hasattr(Meta, "abstract") and getattr(Meta, "abstract"):
                # if the class is abstract, don't create permissions for it, just return the class object            
                return super(MyModelMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)

        if not Meta:
            # create a new Meta Class
            Meta = type('Meta', (object,), {})

        setattr(Meta, 'permissions',(("read_%s"%name.lower(), "Can read %s"%name.lower()),))
        attrs['Meta'] = Meta
        return super(MyModelMeta, cls).__new__(cls, name, bases, attrs)
```

create an abstract django models and set the meta class memeber to MyModelMeta:

```
class MyAbstractModel(models.Model):
    __metaclass__ = MyModelMeta

    class Meta:
        abstract=True
```

now, create a normal django model like so:

```
class SomeModel(MyAbstractModel):
    someFieldName = models.CharField(max_length=256, db_index=True)
```

this will generate the default add/change/delete_somemodel permissions, but also
it will add a new read_somemodel permission.

if you're also using south, use this to generate the extra permissions:

```
from django.db.models import get_app, get_models
from django.contrib.auth.management import create_permissions

create_permissions(get_app(app), get_models(), 2 if settings.DEBUG else 0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I write test for your issue.
I use django 1.2.1 and i have great result!

If you want to add permission to your existing model from inherit model, every time when you change them you need to run "syncdb".
Example 100% works.(in 1.2.1 without patch)

It now works.

[alt text http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/7500/permn.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/7500/permn.png)

**Example:**

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib import admin

class permissions(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        permissions = (("test_permission","test permission"),)


class SomeClass(permissions):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255,verbose_name="Name")

admin.site.register(SomeClass)
```

Comment: thanks, good to know that it is supposed to work like this... so i have to find out why it doesnt!

Comment: Found out what the problem is: If the child class has her own inner Meta class (that doesnt define any permissions), the permissions are not inherited!

Answer (score 0):

In my case explicitly inheriting the `Meta` didn't work because of South. See [this ticket](http://south.aeracode.org/ticket/211).

`django-admin.py syncdb --all` fixed the problem.