# How to get a more detailed information on an object (a list of fields and methods) using Python's pdb?

Tags: python, django, pdb, django-contenttypes

I am using `pdb` (actually `ipdb`) to debug my Django `models.py`. In particular I am trying to debug these lines of code:

```
def add_can_view( sender, **kwargs ) :
    #import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()
    for content_type in ContentType.objects.all():
        Permission.objects.create(
            content_type = content_type,
            codename     = 'view_{}'.format( content_type.model ),
            name         = 'Can view {}'.format( content_type.name )
        )

post_syncdb.connect( add_can_view )
```

The code above, which was provided in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9939604/is-there-a-way-to-apply-a-meta-permission-to-every-model-in-a-django-app), has an `IntegrityError` error when I run `python manage.py syncdb`:

```
ERROR: An unexpected error occurred while tokenizing input
The following traceback may be corrupted or invalid
The error message is: ('EOF in multi-line statement', (11, 0))
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IntegrityError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/IPython/utils/py3compat.pyc in execfile(fname, *where)
    173             else:
    174                 filename = fname
--> 175             __builtin__.execfile(filename, *where)

/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/manage.py in <module>()
      8     from django.core.management import execute_from_command_line
      9 
---> 10     execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.pyc in execute_from_command_line(argv)
    441     """
    442     utility = ManagementUtility(argv)
--> 443     utility.execute()
    444 
    445 def execute_manager(settings_mod, argv=None):

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.pyc in execute(self)
    380             sys.stdout.write(self.main_help_text() + '\n')
    381         else:
--> 382             self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
    383 
    384 def setup_environ(settings_mod, original_settings_path=None):

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.pyc in run_from_argv(self, argv)
    194         options, args = parser.parse_args(argv[2:])
    195         handle_default_options(options)
--> 196         self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
    197 
    198     def execute(self, *args, **options):

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.pyc in execute(self, *args, **options)
    230             if self.requires_model_validation:
    231                 self.validate()
--> 232             output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    233             if output:
    234                 if self.output_transaction:

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.pyc in handle(self, *args, **options)
    369         if args:
    370             raise CommandError("Command doesn't accept any arguments")
--> 371         return self.handle_noargs(**options)
    372 
    373     def handle_noargs(self, **options):

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/South-0.7.4-py2.7.egg/south/management/commands/syncdb.pyc in handle_noargs(self, migrate_all, **options)
     88 
     89         # OK, run the actual syncdb

---> 90         syncdb.Command().execute(**options)
     91 
     92         settings.INSTALLED_APPS = old_installed

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.pyc in execute(self, *args, **options)
    230             if self.requires_model_validation:
    231                 self.validate()
--> 232             output = self.handle(*args, **options)
    233             if output:
    234                 if self.output_transaction:

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/base.pyc in handle(self, *args, **options)
    369         if args:
    370             raise CommandError("Command doesn't accept any arguments")
--> 371         return self.handle_noargs(**options)
    372 
    373     def handle_noargs(self, **options):

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/syncdb.pyc in handle_noargs(self, **options)
    108         # Send the post_syncdb signal, so individual apps can do whatever they need

    109         # to do at this point.

--> 110         emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
    111 
    112         # The connection may have been closed by a syncdb handler.


/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/management/sql.pyc in emit_post_sync_signal(created_models, verbosity, interactive, db)
    187         models.signals.post_syncdb.send(sender=app, app=app,
    188             created_models=created_models, verbosity=verbosity,
--> 189             interactive=interactive, db=db)

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/dispatch/dispatcher.pyc in send(self, sender, **named)
    170 
    171         for receiver in self._live_receivers(_make_id(sender)):
--> 172             response = receiver(signal=self, sender=sender, **named)
    173             responses.append((receiver, response))
    174         return responses

/Users/hobbes3/Sites/mysite/doors/signals.py in add_can_view(sender, **kwargs)
      8             content_type = content_type,
      9             codename     = 'view_{}'.format( content_type.model ),
---> 10             name         = 'Can view {}'.format( content_type.name )
     11         )
     12 

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in create(self, **kwargs)
    135 
    136     def create(self, **kwargs):
--> 137         return self.get_query_set().create(**kwargs)
    138 
    139     def bulk_create(self, *args, **kwargs):

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in create(self, **kwargs)
    375         obj = self.model(**kwargs)
    376         self._for_write = True
--> 377         obj.save(force_insert=True, using=self.db)
    378         return obj
    379 

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.pyc in save(self, force_insert, force_update, using)
    461         if force_insert and force_update:
    462             raise ValueError("Cannot force both insert and updating in model saving.")
--> 463         self.save_base(using=using, force_insert=force_insert, force_update=force_update)
    464 
    465     save.alters_data = True

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.pyc in save_base(self, raw, cls, origin, force_insert, force_update, using)
    549 
    550                 update_pk = bool(meta.has_auto_field and not pk_set)
--> 551                 result = manager._insert([self], fields=fields, return_id=update_pk, using=using, raw=raw)
    552 
    553                 if update_pk:

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.pyc in _insert(self, objs, fields, **kwargs)
    201 
    202     def _insert(self, objs, fields, **kwargs):
--> 203         return insert_query(self.model, objs, fields, **kwargs)
    204 
    205     def _update(self, values, **kwargs):

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.pyc in insert_query(model, objs, fields, return_id, raw, using)
   1574     query = sql.InsertQuery(model)
   1575     query.insert_values(fields, objs, raw=raw)
-> 1576     return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)
   1577 
   1578 

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.pyc in execute_sql(self, return_id)
    908         cursor = self.connection.cursor()
    909         for sql, params in self.as_sql():
--> 910             cursor.execute(sql, params)
    911         if not (return_id and cursor):
    912             return

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/util.pyc in execute(self, sql, params)
     38         start = time()
     39         try:
---> 40             return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
     41         finally:
     42             stop = time()

/Users/hobbes3/.virtualenvs/doors/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/postgresql_psycopg2/base.pyc in execute(self, query, args)
     50     def execute(self, query, args=None):
     51         try:
---> 52             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)
     53         except Database.IntegrityError, e:
     54             raise utils.IntegrityError, utils.IntegrityError(*tuple(e)), sys.exc_info()[2]

IntegrityError: duplicate key value violates unique constraint "auth_permission_content_type_id_codename_key"
DETAIL:  Key (content_type_id, codename)=(2, view_group) already exists.
```

I have a feeling that somehow there is a duplicate `content_type` and the error occurs when I try to apply the permission twice to `content_type_id 2`, which is `auth.group`. So when after I uncomment the `import ipdb` line, I want to check out some objects such as `content_type`, but if I type that, then all I get is `<ContentType: content type>`.

I know I can simply go look at the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/contrib/contenttypes/) to see the model, but how would you get a list of fields and methods without knowing what the class is?

Also bonus points for solving this error lol.

Comment: In case anyone is interested, `post_syncdb` is called for *every* app installed in `setttings.py`. So you need to place a line like `if Permission.objects.filter( content_type_id = content_type.pk, codename__contains = 'view_' ) is None :` to check to make sure that the permissions aren't applied more than once per `content_type`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `dir` (e.g. `dir(content_type)`) to get a list of attributes (including methods).

In relation to django models, there is also a lot of information inside the `_meta` property. Explore that with `dir(my_model_object._meta)`.

Answer (score 2):

Your choices are:

1. [dir](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir) to get a list of the attributes and methods of an object
2. `content_type.__class__` to learn the class of the object
3. [help](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#help) to show the documentation in the console so you don't have to look it up

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `ipdb` (and not `pdb`), a faster alternative to `dir` is using the built-in tab completion:

```
ipdb> foo=""
ipdb> foo.           #press tab after writing the dot
foo.capitalize  foo.islower     foo.rpartition
foo.center      foo.isspace     foo.rsplit
foo.count       foo.istitle     foo.rstrip
foo.decode      foo.isupper     foo.split
foo.encode      foo.join        foo.splitlines
foo.endswith    foo.ljust       foo.startswith
foo.expandtabs  foo.lower       foo.strip
foo.find        foo.lstrip      foo.swapcase
foo.format      foo.partition   foo.title
foo.index       foo.replace     foo.translate
foo.isalnum     foo.rfind       foo.upper
foo.isalpha     foo.rindex      foo.zfill
foo.isdigit     foo.rjusthere
```

In case you don't know about it, you can also use tab completion to complete variable names

Comment: Another (totally unrelated but) great feature to know about in `pdb` is [command history reverse search](http://lifehacker.com/278888/ctrl%252Br-to-search-and-other-terminal-history-tricks) (the article is about shells, but same principles apply)